# Получить реальное время телефона

Tags: android, android-sdk

Всем привет. Возникла сложность: у меня nexus 7 с android 4.4.4. Когда я пытаюсь получить в студии время (и через System.currentTimeMillis и через Calendar.getInstance), то мне возвращает время с отставанием на час. Как можно исправить данную ситуацию? При этом, на android 5+ с этим все в порядке.

Comment: Может все дело в часовом поясе?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да, покапался, именно так, в часовом поясе дело. Но сути это не меняет, как можно получить реальное время устройства? Тот же самый "будильник" то не зависит от часового пояса...

Comment: Что значит "реальное время"? Есть время UTC, есть время пользователя (UTC скорректированное на часовой пояс из пользовательских настроек).